# Pull out categorical rows and apply to all subsequent rows until new category found

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a dummy DataFrame of my data, I have categorical rows (represented by the existence of `NaN` value of `'Price'`) and data rows (represented by a non-`NaN`
value of `'Price'`).

```
gear = [('Baseball', None), ('Bat', 1), ('Glove', 2), ('Soccer', None), ('Shoes', 3), ('Ball', 4), ('Football', None), ('Helmet', 6)]
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(gear, columns=['Name', 'Price'])

       Name  Price
0  Baseball    NaN
1       Bat    1.0
2     Glove    2.0
3    Soccer    NaN
4     Shoes    3.0
5      Ball    4.0
6  Football    NaN
7    Helmet    6.0
```

I would like to create a new column `'Sport'` which is applied to each row under the category of course until you reach the next sport. The resulting DataFrame would look like this with the categorical rows removed:

```
       Name  Price     Sport
1       Bat    1.0  Baseball
2     Glove    2.0  Baseball
3     Shoes    3.0    Soccer
4      Ball    4.0    Soccer
5    Helmet    6.0  Football
```

I was thinking of creating a new column `'Sport'` which is the value of `Name` if `Price` is not `NaN` otherwise `NaN`. Then use a `ffill` or something and then drop the `NaN` price rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `mask` the `notna`, then `ffill` to get the correct `Sport`:

```
s = dummy_df['Price'].notna()
dummy_df.assign(Sport=dummy_df['Name'].mask(s).ffill()).loc[s]
```

Output:

```
     Name  Price     Sport
1     Bat    1.0  Baseball
2   Glove    2.0  Baseball
4   Shoes    3.0    Soccer
5    Ball    4.0    Soccer
7  Helmet    6.0  Football
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dummy_df["Sport"] = dummy_df.groupby(dummy_df.Price.isna().cumsum()).Name.transform("first")
dummy_df[dummy_df.Price.notna()]
#      Name  Price     Sport
# 1     Bat    1.0  Baseball
# 2   Glove    2.0  Baseball
# 4   Shoes    3.0    Soccer
# 5    Ball    4.0    Soccer
# 7  Helmet    6.0  Football
```